# How to create tests in a Spring boot application without the main class (using Mockito)

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing

I have a library, the project is written in springbot, but there is no need to use main class here

```java
interface Helper{
  String transform(int index);
}
```

```java
class HelperImpl implements Helper{

private final Convert convert();

  public Helper(Convert convert){

  this.convert = convert.
 }

 public String transform(int index){

   int res = convert.print(index);

   return  String.valueOf(res);
 }
}
```

```java
interface Convert {
int print(int value);

}
```

```java
class ConvertImpl implements Convert{

public int print(int value){
    return 1;
  }

}
```

```java
@DisplayName("Message ")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Slf4j
class Test {

    @Autowired
    Helper helper;

    @Autowired
    Convert convert;


    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
      }

    @Test
    void testRun() {
      
     String result = helper.transform(1);

  }
}
```

How can I write an integration test, during the raising of which an inject would be automatically made and I would only have to call methods through the received instances, pass values, get the result and check it.   This is the same inject and it does not work.

Comment: I suppose that you're trying to run your test like a classic junit5 test? @Autowired is a Spring annotation, but you're not running your test using Spring, hence, it cannot work. You need to manually instantiate your Helper and Convert classes.

Comment: This is true. I did it. but maybe I can use a Mosquito that is autowired. I mean, is it possible to do this without resorting to creating an instance manually?

Comment: If the only thing you need is an instance and want a simple unit test, create the instance yourself and mock the needed dependencies. The fact that you use Spring doesn't mean you need to use it everywhere! In fact a test without Spring (a simple unit test) will run much faster without a Spring Context being created than relying on one being created.

Comment: I agree with that. but spring is connected due to the fact that it has all the necessary dependencies for the library being developed and I'm trying to use its capabilities to some extent. that's why I tried to apply the features from Spring to the tests as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @Autowired annotation is a Spring annotation, hence cannot be used without a Spring context being loaded. 
There are three usual solutions to provide the instances of the classes required by the classes under test :

### Manual instantiations

You don't use Spring, and instantiate the dependencies using the *new* keyword, or using Mockito for the dependencies that have to be mocked. Constructor injection is preferred to field injection, as it will allow you to easily bypass Spring in your unit tests.

**Pros** : Faster to run. Easier to configure 
**Cons :** It can sometimes be complex to manually provide all the required dependencies. If your code heavily relies on Spring features, then, in some situations, it can be a bit more complex to use this solution.

### Using @SpringBootTest

You want to rely on the same Spring configuration that you will use at runtime, then you should use the Springboot solution : the *@SpringBootTest* annotation, and the *@MockBean* annotation for the dependencies that you want to mock.
**Pros :** Facilitate the dependency injection. Spring features can be used in the tests. It's easy to mock the dependencies with the @MockBean annotation. 
**Cons :** The Spring application context is required and can be slow to initialize in large projects. Note that it will be reused between tests if it doesn't have to change.

### Using SpringExtension

You'll have to provide a Spring configuration that will define the beans that you want to autowire.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringTestConfiguration.class })
public class MyTest { 
  
  @Autowired
  Helper helper;

  ...
}

@Configuration
public class SpringTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Helper helper() { return new Helper(); }
  }
}
```

Comment: An annotation @SpringBootTest unfortunately it will not work if there is not main class (Tests are writing for custom library)

Comment: Ok, I added another option, that could fit a bit better with your requirements, if you really want to rely on the autowired annotations in your unit tests. The ExtendWith annotation is for Junit5. Look at runWith(SpringRunner.class) if you're still using junit4.